# bash: rsync: command not found

Tags: osx, zsh, rsync, iterm, prezto

I'm on OSX using iTerm (3) with [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) as my zsh configuration framework.
I've a strange error message when I use `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude='.git' src/ remote:/dst
bash: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

When I check the path to `rsync` I see:

```
$ which rsync
rsync: aliased to noglob rsync
$ type -a rsync
rsync is an alias for noglob rsync
rsync is /usr/bin/rsync
```

It seems that it's an alias declared by prezto that uses the `noglob` macro.
I also tried to call the rsync command with `/usr/bin/rsync` but didn't help.

Any idea what's wrong here??

Comment: What is the output of `type -a rsync` ?

Comment: I updated the post with the result of `type -a rsync`.

Comment: `rsync: command not found`. Dude ...

Comment: It should **not** be off-topic question! I had the same issue, and the answer actually helped me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out `rsync` has to be installed on the remote machine. I just did and now it works fine.

Comment: Had the same issue, thanks!